# remove white spaces followed by any till comma using sed or awk

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, gawk

My file has the below comma separated values

```
dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com       80,versioncheck-bg.addons.mozilla.org   80,     ,frontweb-stg.shoprunner.com    443,p.typekit.net       443,sra.s-9.us  443,www.shoprunner.com     443,cdn.optimizely.com  443,logx.optimizely.com 443,sra.s-9.us  443,ocsp.digicert.com   443,code.jquery.com     443,ocsp2.globalsign.com        443,dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com 443,versioncheck-bg.addons.mozilla.org  443,    ,
```

few places i see empty space followed by comma

I would like to have the below output:

```
dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com,versioncheck-bg.addons.mozilla.org,,frontweb-stg.shoprunner.com,p.typekit.net,sra.s-9.us,www.shoprunner.com,cdn.optimizely.com,logx.optimizely.com,sra.s-9.us,ocsp.digicert.com,code.jquery.com,ocsp2.globalsign.com,dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com,versioncheck-bg.addons.mozilla.org,,
```

Ideally I want remove whitespaces till i see comma,

I tried with

```
sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*,/,/g' sample.file
```

but nothing favoured.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want to remove the numbers such as `80` as well?

Comment: yes I want to see only urls and no portnumbers.

Comment: sed -i 's/[[:space:]][^,]*,/,/g' this solution works for me, but if my file has the line like A B c,dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com       80,versioncheck-bg.addons.mozilla.org   80, I want remove only numbers but this solution is generic for all values followed by space and till , I tried with 's/[[:space:]][^[[0-9]*],]*,/,/g' , i am not sure, what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `^` means beginning of line. Remove it.

Secondly, you appear to want to remove all non-commas between each space and the following comma, but you didn't include that in the pattern.

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:]][^,]*,/,/g' sample.file
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Neither this helped me.
I am looking to remove whitespaces and whitespaces followed by numbers

Comment: Re "*Neither this helped me*", Fixed. The `*` got left out accidentally. // Re "*I am looking to remove whitespaces and whitespaces followed by numbers*", If the Question is wrong, please fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. can you please explain me, it would be more helpful for my understanding.

Comment: huh? I already explained each change! I removed `^` because you don't want to match the beginning of the line, and I changed `[[:space:]]*` to `[[:space:]][^,]*` because you want to match the junk between the spaces and the comma.

Comment: ikegami, the solution works like charm for me, i have got in other problem, this solution removes every junk followed by space and end with comma, can we limit this to do , ifand if we have an integer alone.
I tried with sed -i 's/[[:space:]][^0-9,]*,/,/g' sample.file and its not working as expected, can you please let me know, what i missed, when i try this with vim editor and work :%s/[[:space:]][^0-9,]*,/,/g this works.

Comment: There's no way that worked in vim, since `[^0-9,]` means "a char other than a digit or comma". /// If your question needs updating, do so. Don't post edits in the comments. Or if you're asking a new question, similarly don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{gsub(/[ ]+/,"")gsub(/[0,3-8]/,"")}1' file
```

The first gsub removes space and the next one takes away unwanted numbers.

Comment: please explain more in detail for non awk-masters

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\s+\d*(?=,)//g' file
```

Perl's startup cost is higher than, say, Sed's or Awk's, but Perl's more powerful regular expression support often makes things easier:

- `\s` is a convenient shortcut for matching whitespace (tab, space, newline); similarly, `\d` is a shortcut for `[0-9]`.
- `+` as the one-or-more-instances duplication symbol is always available, whereas to use it *portably* in `sed` you'd have to use the awkward `\{1,\}` construct.
- `(?=...)` is a look-ahead assertion that allows looking for a subexpression without including it in the match.